# PHP, Active Directory, User Account Control

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

First of appologies if this should be on server-fault, but it's to do with PHP as well, so I thought this the best site for it.

I'm creating a few methods to integrate our intranet with Active Directory. One of the methods will automatically search our database for new users, and create user accounts in AD if new users are found.

Likewise, if a user is marked as left in the database, it will automatically disable the account in active directory.

I've been looking at the attributes passed from active directory, and in particular the User Account Control field.

On the [microsoft website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144) it states this under its list of attributes:

```
The following table lists possible flags that you can assign. You cannot set some 
of the values on a user or computer object because these values can be set or 
reset only by the directory service. The flags are cumulative. To disable a 
user's account, set the UserAccountControl attribute to 0x0202 (0x002 + 0x0200). In 
decimal, this is 514 (2 + 512).
```

**Question**
My question is, if we use the example above, to mark a record as a user (512) and disabled (2), this ultimately makes the field value returned by AD as 514.

In PHP, how can I extract what flags have been marked on the record? For example, If given `514`, how can I use PHP to work out that its a normal user account, and also disabled (2 and 512)?

For example split the following:

```
Flag    | Splits into      | Flag Meaning
--------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
514     | 512 + 2          | Normal User Account + Disabled
522     | 512 + 2 + 8      | Normal User Account + Disabled + Home Directory Required
8389120 | 8388608 + 512    | Password Expired + Normal User Account
```

I hope you can understand my question, but feel free to ask for confirmation or more details.

Many thanks

Comment: What PHP utility are you using to access Active Directory? I'd like to know for a similar intranet requirement I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Came upon the same situation today and it is more concise with:

```
$flag_to_find = 530;
$flags = array();
for ($i=0; $i<=26; $i++){
  if ($flag_to_find & (1 << $i)){
    array_push($flags, 1 << $i);
  }  
}
print_r($flags);
```

Comment: I like this method more than my own! Thanks for an additional (better) answer :)

Comment: This is awesome, was looking everywhere for this, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Adding to James Sloan's answer, here is the flag list :

```
public function findFlags($flag) {

    $flags    = array();
    $flaglist = array(
               1 => 'SCRIPT',
               2 => 'ACCOUNTDISABLE',
               8 => 'HOMEDIR_REQUIRED',
              16 => 'LOCKOUT',
              32 => 'PASSWD_NOTREQD',
              64 => 'PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE',
             128 => 'ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PWD_ALLOWED',
             256 => 'TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT',
             512 => 'NORMAL_ACCOUNT',
            2048 => 'INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT',
            4096 => 'WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT',
            8192 => 'SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT',
           65536 => 'DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD',
          131072 => 'MNS_LOGON_ACCOUNT',
          262144 => 'SMARTCARD_REQUIRED',
          524288 => 'TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION',
         1048576 => 'NOT_DELEGATED',
         2097152 => 'USE_DES_KEY_ONLY',
         4194304 => 'DONT_REQ_PREAUTH',
         8388608 => 'PASSWORD_EXPIRED',
        16777216 => 'TRUSTED_TO_AUTH_FOR_DELEGATION',
        67108864 => 'PARTIAL_SECRETS_ACCOUNT'
    );
    for ($i=0; $i<=26; $i++){
        if ($flag & (1 << $i)){
            array_push($flags, 1 << $i);
        }
    }
    foreach($flags as $k=>&$v) {
        $v = $v . ' '  . $flaglist[$v];
    }
    return $flags;
}
```

Comment: Working like a charm ! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think that even though the original post asks in a general way, the problem is specific to just certain flags that need to be checked. Using the very helpful list in Bill C's response:

```
$userAccountControl = 514; // Get this from AD

// using bitwise AND: 
// this will be the right hand value if it's set, 0 if not

$isAccountDisabled = ($userAccountControl & 2) == 2; 
$isNormalAccount = ($userAccountControl & 512) == 512;
```

And if the need is to update the value (which I think is the programmatic need of the original question, such as enabling the account):

```
$userAccountControl = 514; // Get this from AD

// using bitwise AND NOT: 
// this will assure the right hand value is not set

$userAccountControl = $userAccountControl & ~2; // enable the account

// using bitwise OR:
// this will assure the right hand value is set

$userAccountControl = $userAccountControl | 512; // assure normal account
```

There is a nice abstract function example in the php bitwise operators docs that could be used to develop a generalized solution for AD flags: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php#108679.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after a lot of trial and error, I've worked out how to do it!

```
$bits = array(
    '27' => 1, '26' => 2, '25' => 4, '24' => 8, '23' => 16, '22' => 32, 
    '21' => 64, '20' => 128, '19' => 256, '18' => 512, '17' => 1024, 
    '16' => 2048, '15' => 4096, '14' => 8192, '13' => 16328, 
    '12' => 32768, '11' => 65536, '10' => 131072, '9' => 262144, 
    '8' => 524288, '7' => 1048576, '6' => 2097152, '5' => 4194304, 
    '4' => 8388608, '3' => 16777216, '2' => 33554432, '1' => 67108864
);

$flag_to_find = 530;   // Indicates a normal user account, which is disabled, and locked out

$binary = str_pad(decbin($flag_to_find), count($bits), 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

$flags = array();

for($i=0; $i<strlen($binary); $i++)
{
    if($binary[$i]==1)
{
        $flags[] = $bits[$i+1];
    }
}

print_r($flags);

// Outputs: 512: Normal User Account
            16:  Locked Out Account
            2:   Disabled Accout
```

It works by getting the decimal values of ALL possible flags in the UAC. There are 27 - I've assigned all values to the `$bits` array.

You then specify a flag to find.

Then convert the decimal value of the flag, to binary, and left pad it with `0`.

Loop through each value in the binary string. If the iteration value is `1`, get its associated flag decimal value from the `$bits` array.

All possible flags are then stored in the `$flags` array.

Hope this helps anyone in future with similar problems!